# Interleaving the bits

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to interleave the inputs before generating the output.
I have 64 bits input and 64 bits output.
I tried the code like this.
But, I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

```
for (integer i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
   out[i*4] = in[i];
   out[(i*4) +1] = in[i+16];
   out[(i*4) +2] = in[i+32];
   out[(i*4) +3] = in[i+48];
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "efficient" you mean more compact code, then you can use nested `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) begin
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) begin
        out[ (i*4) + j ] = in[ i + (j*16) ];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    out[i*4 +: 4] = {in[i],in[i+16],in[i+32],in[i+48]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, `out` would follow order:

```
00 16 32 48    01 17 33 49    02 18 34 50    ...    15 31 47 63
```

In SystemVerilog that can be compressed to:

```
    foreach(out[i]) out[i] = in[ 16*(i%4) + (i/4) ];
```

or the equivalent:

```
    foreach(in[i]) out[ 4*(i%16) + (i/16) ] = in[i];
```

You original code and my compressed solutions are logically equivalent. Any decent synthesizer would treat them the same. Fewer lines of code will not change anything. It really comes down to human readability and how you plan to handle future changes to the interleave function.

From the simulation perspective, modular and division operations are more resource intensive. A good simulator should recognize 4 and 16 are powers of 2 and optimize the math for it. If not, try replacing `16*(i%4) + (i/4)` with `{(i[1:0]+i[6]),i[5:2]}` (note: simplest logic and less human readable). You should not see a meaningful performance difference with a descent simulator.